# Implementing search on List page using with AngularJS/MVC5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to implement the search on the List page.

The below code works when it comes to displaying the data as a list, but I'm not sure how to begin with implementing the search feature to this page.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="empCtrl" class="container">

      <div>
         <input type="text" ng-model="search_filter" placeholder="Search" />
       </div>

        <div class="container" infinite-scroll="pagedata()">
            <div>
                <div>
                    Id
                </div>
                <div>
                    Name
                </div>
                <div>
                    Description
                </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-repeat="emp in emps | filter: search_filter"> //<<<<
                <div class="column fifth">
                    {{emp.Id}}
                </div>
                <div class="column fifth">
                    {{emp.Name}}
                </div>
                <div class="column fifth">
                    {{emp.Description}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

MVC Controller:

```
public ActionResult Employee()
{
    var model = new EmployeeViewModel();
    var employees = GetEmployees();
    model.EmployeeList = employees;
    return View("List", model);
}
```

Angular:

```
myApp.controller('empCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.employees = $window.EmployeeViewModel;

    $scope.pagedata = function () {
        $http.get($scope.getBaseUrl()).success(function (data) {
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You should look into filtering through angular. Here's an advanced example, but if you look around you should be able to find different ones. http://jsfiddle.net/ed9A2/1/

Comment: it was typo, i fixed it.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall: I tried adding filter to `ng-repeat` but does not do anything, i have updated my question. `ng-repeat="emp in emps | filter: search_filter">`

Comment: @AbuHamzah Make sure the text input is a child of your controller div so you have access to the scope.

Comment: i have updated the question and yes its within the Contoller div but i do not see any when i run the page and type in textbox.

Comment: @AbuHamzah Are you planning on implementing server-side or client-side search?

Comment: @ShayNissel: Its a very good question you have asked and the answer to your question is server-side and when the user type in the search input box and and i will call the api to fetch the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are interested in server-side search, you will need to change your approach a little.

The data you are retrieving right now is populate when the page is retrieved. I would suggest to move it to a separate Action or WebAPI controller like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult List(string text)
{
    var employees = GetEmployeesByText(text);
    return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I assume you will implement the `GetEmployeesByText` with the necessary functionality.

And then fetch the data in the angular controller:

```
myApp.controller('empCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.employees = null;
    $scope.search_filter = null;

    $scope.getEmployees = function(text){
        $http.get('/Employee/List?text=' + $scope.search_filter)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.employees = data; 
            });
    };

    $scope.getEmployees();
});
```

And last:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="empCtrl" class="container">

      <div>
         <input type="text" ng-model="search_filter" placeholder="Search" ng-change="getEmployees()" />
       </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <div>
                    Id
                </div>
                <div>
                    Name
                </div>
                <div>
                    Description
                </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                <div class="column fifth">
                    {{emp.Id}}
                </div>
                <div class="column fifth">
                    {{emp.Name}}
                </div>
                <div class="column fifth">
                    {{emp.Description}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What it takes to do the client-side search implementation?

Comment: add `| filter: search_filter` to the `ng-repeat` and remove the `ng-change`.